# Using multiple counters with one method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to keep my practice application as minimal as possible, how would I change my method to allow multiple counters to use one state variable but not change each counter when I increase or decrease?

```
<template>
  <h1>Test Counter</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemName">Item 1</div>
      <button @click="decreaseCount">Decrease</button>
      <div class="value">{{ count }}</div>
      <button @click="increaseCount">Increase</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemName">Item 2</div>
      <button @click="decreaseCount">Decrease</button>
      <div class="value">{{ count }}</div>
      <button @click="increaseCount">Increase</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increaseCount() {
      this.count += 1;
    },
    decreaseCount() {
      this.count -= 1;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I have a very basic working example here where I have left the problem in the application - https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-hill-p6kum?file=/src/App.vue

I have tried to rename the state to it's own variable so each counter then has it's own state but when I have changed that the counter will not increase or decrease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this out

```
<template>
  <h1>Test Counter</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemName">Item 1</div>
      <button @click="decreaseCount('counterOne')">Decrease</button>
      <div class="value">{{ counterOne }}</div>
      <button @click="increaseCount('counterOne')">Increase</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemName">Item 2</div>
      <button @click="decreaseCount('counterTwo">Decrease</button>
      <div class="value">{{ counterTwo }}</div>
      <button @click="increaseCount('counterTwo')">Increase</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      counterOne: 0,
      counterTwo: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increaseCount(val) {
      this[val] += 1;
    },
    decreaseCount(val) {
      this[val] -= 1;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Another way

```
<template>
  <h1>Test Counter</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <div class="itemName">{{item.name}}</div>
      <button @click="decreaseCount(index)">Decrease</button>
      <div class="value">{{ item.counter }}</div>
      <button @click="increaseCount(index)">Increase</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      Items: [
       { name: 'Item 1',  counter: 0 },
       { name: 'Item 1',  counter: 0 },
        ....... 
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increaseCount(val) {
      this.items[val].counter += 1;
    },
    decreaseCount(val) {
      this.items[val].counter -= 1;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: That works but i'm now essentially just using two different state variables, eventually there will be 20+ different counters so is this the most efficient way to have counterOne... counterTwenty...

Comment: I need to know one thing..are you going to show the items by iterating the div using v-for?

Comment: no each item will be unique to it's own component, but each component will use the same counter method from the parent

Comment: Please check my edited answer...if that's not how your implementation is going to be then the former is the only way

Comment: Please give an upvote if that helped @ShrewdStyle